# TCP server test

Tags: testing, asynchronous, synchronous, tcpserver

i have a TCP server (listener) software written in C#. Many devices (approximately 5000) will connect to server asynchronously and send/receive messages to/from server. Now, i have 2 questions.

1. I have to send reply messages to every received message. Which way should i use? Asynchronous (asap when message received) or synchronous (sending replies using a reply task).
2. How can i strain test my server? I can communicate with 1-2 computers successfully but i don't know that my software works fine for 5000 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what your saying, your server or listener is expected to be available to respond to multiple requests at any given time. The key is how has it been implemented ? Does the server support multi client response, in other words can it fulfill requests of multiple clients at the same time ? May be using multiple threads etc ! Or does it use a queue to keep track of all requests and then serve them in a orderly fashion, or does it use some other method to serve requests !

Comment: I have a cross-thread implementation in server software so i expect to communicate multi devices.

Comment: Then it should work fine the way you are saying, idle response would be asynchronous

Comment: To stress test you may create multiple threads tht request service from the server ! That way you could see if it works for as many threads as you wish

Comment: Is there a standard tool to test the software?